# Don't know what IndexOutOfRangeException means

Tags: c#, arrays, indexoutofrangeexception

I am attempting an insertion sort algorithm in c# and struggling to fix this error message:

> "System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in algorithmsAssignment.exe"

As soon as it reaches the while loop, the code breaks and gives me the message. Any help would be appreciated

(I have had to do string.compare as I'm using a 2D array string.

```
static void insertionSort(int columnSort, bool accendingOrder)
    {
        int column = columnSort - 1;
        int i, j;

        for (i = 1; i < dataArray.GetLength(1); i++)
        {
            string key = dataArray[column, i];
            j = i - 1;

            /* Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that are
               greater than key, to one position ahead
               of their current position */
            while (j >= 0 && string.Compare(dataArray[column, j - 1], 
dataArray[j, column]) > 0)
            {
                dataArray[column, j + 1] = dataArray[column, j];
                j = j - 1;
            }
            dataArray[column, j + 1] = key;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to alarm you, but I think there's a very good chance that you're using an index that's less than zero, or greater than or equal to the count of items in the indexed array.

Comment: Have you tried to look it up in the docs? It's pretty well described https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

In your first for iteration: ( i = 1 )

```
string key = dataArray[column, i];
j = i - 1;
// J value is 0


while (j >= 0 && string.Compare(dataArray[column, j - 1], //Here, j - 1 = -1, since j = 0
....
....
```

I bet there is your index out of range, since index -1 can't exist.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You will get error for i=1 because you have this conditions:

```
 j = i - 1; //j=0 for i=1
```

and wrong condition in while loop

```
while (j >= 0 && string.Compare(dataArray[column, j - 1], 
dataArray[j, column]) > 0)
```

this condition in while loop `dataArray[column, j - 1]` will throw `IndexOutOfRange` exception because

```
j-1=-1 for j=0
```